# Floating box to the right

Tags: html, css, floating, box

I'm currently creating a website, which has a centered box with text and and such.
Now, i also want a box floating on the right, with a little gap from my main box.
I'll leave a picture here, where the red box i drew is the floating box i want to make.

[image]

Btw. the blue box is just a censored box i didn't want on the picture.

So my question for you is, how do i make a floating box like that?
I've tried a couple of times with different methods.
in the CSS, i've made a box and gave it the property float:right; 
But when i do that, it just turns out like this

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: And your current code is where?

Comment: What code do you have with you?

Comment: CSS: .main {
    width: 500px;
     border: 2px solid #C33;
 border-bottom-width: 2px;
 background-color: #252525;
    min-height: 1000px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.side {
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #C33;
    min-height: 100px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 100px;
 background-color:#252525;
}
.wrapper {
    margin-top:10px;
    width: 760px;

} HTML: <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
    test main
    </div>
    <div class="side">
    test side
    </div>
</div>

Comment: @user3091051 Please add that code to your question by clicking edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p3W2X/1/)**

You can keep an element center align by defining its `width` then using `margin: 0 auto;` technique. this will make sure your center div is in center then you can use `position: absolute` to create the other box on offset position.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="main">This is in center position.</div>
    <div class="side">This is in offset position.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
.main-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.main, .main-wrapper {
    width: 500px;
}
.main {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.side {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    right: -300px;
}
.main, .side {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have a problem though. I want my "main" in the center, and 500px wide. Then i want the "side" 200px wide and next to it. But So i set the wrapper to 700px, but for some reason the "side" push the "main" more to the left so it's not any longer centered. Picture here: http://i.imgur.com/SsDEUOL.png

Comment: You can not keep 1 div center & other to it's left at the same time like that -- i would suggest using `position: absolute;` or negative margin.. i have updated my answer to show you absolute positioning technique.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you have a `<div>` with a `float: right;` in the end. Keep it in the first code. So that it gets floated correctly. I would code this way:

```
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="main">
  Main Contents
</div>
```

CSS would be:

```
.right {float: right; width: 20%;}
.main {margin: auto; width: 60%;}
```

#### Preview:

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/8WHyp/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

U can have main container `display : inline-block`

width of each sub container as `width : 30%;`

and width of the floating box which is inside 3rd sub container as

```
width : 100%;
```

In case u dont need first div,

put some margin for the 2nd container

ex .. `margin-left : 300px;`

and in case u dont want ur floating box width to be 100% of the 3rd container, u can adjust it too